# Google pagespeed insights CSS warnings

Tags: html, css, pagespeed

I read many articles about optimization and after many efforts I minified all my CSS files and gathered all of them in one file. When I check again with PageSpeed Insights I still get low points and google still suggests me to remove the only left CSS file. here is the link of  [my site](http://sirtcantalilar.com) . Simply I have only this minified CSS in the head section.

```
    <html lang="tr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>| sirtcantalilar.com </title>
        <link href="/assets2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

How can I optimize delivery of my website ?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I know is to [minify](https://cssminifier.com/) the CSS file and include it inline in the head tag of your html file

```
<head>
  <style>
  ..minified CSS here
  </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not using too much background images.And the CDN you are using is loading your site very slow.And also that twitter widget you are using is causing your page to load slow.Remove twitter widget to test if your site loads fast enough or not.

Comment: removed twitter. removed one of bgs. removed CDN. it is getting better but still points are between 70 in mobile, 80 in desktop.